# using esttab: how to specify number of digits for summary statitics

Tags: stata

I am using `estpost` and `esttab` to produce a table of summary statistics. But I don't know how to specify the number of digits after the decimal points.

```
estpost summarize beauty bmi whr weight height armlength urban age sleep2014 if gender == 1 & year == 2014
est sto m1

estpost summarize beauty bmi whr weight height armlength urban age sleep2014 if gender == 0 & year == 2014
est sto m2

estpost summarize beauty bmi whr weight height armlength urban age if gender == 1 & year == 2012
est sto m3

estpost summarize beauty bmi whr weight height armlength urban age if gender == 0 & year == 2012
est sto m4

esttab m1 m2 m3 m4 using summary.tex, cells("mean sd min max") title(Summary statistics) replace
```

I tried `cells("mean(3) sd(3) min(2) max(2)")`, but it doesn't work. I read through all the examples in http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/estpost.html. All the examples just leave the number of digits as they are originally for summary statistics. It is clearly stated how to do for regression results, but I haven't found anything useful for summary statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example for you:

```
sysuse auto
estpost summarize mpg price
esttab . using summary.tex, title("summary stats") ///
    cells(mean(fmt(%5.3f)) sd(fmt(%5.3f)) min(fmt(%5.2f)) max(fmt(%5.2f)))
```

the important part is that you're using *stat*(fmt(*format*)) in the cells option. 
To find this I used the `help estout` documentation rather than `help esttab`